# How do i swap fans?

Tags: power-supply, fan

I have a 2 pin adapter fan that I want to swap to a 3 pin adapter fan. I bought a "3 pin to 2 pin" adapter but when I connect the adapter to the 3 pin fan, the other end doesn't have pins that can connect to the power supply, like the 2 pin fan has... What can I do?

Power supply cable:

[image: Power supply cable]

2 pin fan cable:

[image: 2 pin fan cable]

Answer (score 0):

You've got a wrong 3pin to 2pin converter. Find a one that matches with the 2pin base or use a 2pin jack and sold it to the cable.

Answer (score 0):

The power supply you are using is for a fan that cools LED grow lights for plants. That's not to say it won't work, its a 12V DC supply with plenty of current sourcing capability, but it certainly doesn't have the same connectorization scheme as a PC case fan, so you will have to add compatible connectors to one or both sides (or just wire them directly for a quick hack).

In a PC typically the supply /mobo side is male and the fan side connector is female:
[image: Fan connector]